# Posicionamiento de divs

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola a todos me encuentro diseñando un filtro de búsqueda con html5 y css3 ya tengo la estructura del proyecto pero no logro posicionar los contenedores al centro y que el ultimo div tenga un background-color naranja.

Esta es la imagen de la estructura que tengo de momento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación dejare el codigo html5

```
  <section id="filter" class="filter">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>Check In</p>
                    <input type="date">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>Check Out</p>
                    <input type="date">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>Cantidad de personas</p>
                    <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="">1</option>
                        <option value="">2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="assets/img/iconos/search.png" alt="search">  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </section>
```

Este es el codigo css que tengo

```
.filter{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:-90px;
    padding: 40px;
    display: flex;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
}

.column{
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.card{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Y aqui la imagen original de como se debería ver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez de floats te recomiendo usar flexbox. El section lo haces flex y luego juegas con cada item

Comment: como puedo pintar la ultima celda completamente ? es que solo me ocupa una parte, como hago para que me ocupe todo el ancho , me refiero a la parte donde esta la lupa @HernánGarcia

Answer (score 1):

Si el resultado esperado es:

[image: result]

Necesita para agregar la clase adicional en la columna con la imagen:

```
<div class="column column__search">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="search.png" alt="search">  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y para modificar algunos de css tambien:

```
.card{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}

.column__search .card {
  height: 100%;
  top: calc(50% - 40px); 
}

.column__search {
  background: #f9ad45;
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.container img { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Generalmente, su código parece un poco excesivamente complicado debido de:

- Uso de `float` - desaprobado
- Uso de los margens negativos - anti-patrón

Uso de `flex` podría ser una mejor opción

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, justo lo que buscaba

Answer (score 0):

como te dije antes, float es una propiedad css que a partir de flexbox ha quedado practicamente en deshuso. Basado en tu estructura (la cual se puede simplificar) yo lo haria asi:

```
<section id="filter" class="filter">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
              <p>Check In</p>
              <input type="date">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
              <p>Check Out</p>
              <input type="date">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
              <p>Cantidad de personas</p>
              <select name="" id="">
                  <option value="">1</option>
                  <option value="">2</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column lupa">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="container">
           <img src="assets/img/iconos/search.png" alt="search">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

css

```
html, body{
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
.filter{
 border-radius: .7rem;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}
filter *{
 height: 100%;
}
.column{
 padding: 0 2rem;
}
.lupa{
 border-radius: 0 .7rem .7rem 0;
 background-color: coral;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Seria largo explicarte como funciona flexbox, te dejo aqui un buen tutorial al respecto: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvq-jIkSeTUbQc3dGsssp8lxAi5npMrys